# New host key every day using MSFTP and WinSCP

Tags: sftp, public-key, winscp

I am tranfering a file from one server to another using "Core FTP mini-sftp-server" on source side and WinSCP on destination side (both servers are running Windows).

I am logging in these two machine using local admin account which are same on both servers.
I have been doing this process manually:

- Start MSFTP server on source
- Start WinSCP on destination, connect to source and get the file.

Now I want to automate it and i tried the following

Start `msftp` from command line on source.

On destination in `winscp.exe` console:

```
open login:password@IPAdress
get <file> <destination>
close
exit
```

The problem with this is if I do it for the first time everyday, it asks me to update the key at the destination side saying:

> "WARNING POTENTIAL SECURITY BREACH!  The server’s host key does not
>   match the one WinSCP has is cache. This means that either the server
>   administrator has charged the host key, the server presents different
>   key under certain circumstances, or you have actually connected to
>   another computer pretending to be the server"

I have to manually do it (click on *Update*) at first and then for the following copies, the automation works.

Question:

*How can I update the key using cmd line while connecting to the server?*

Can I prevent the source to generate new key daily? Or should I do it?

Comment: The servers are Windows machines by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should prevent the source server generating a new key - there is absolutely no reason to do so. The server's public key identifies the server, and so this identity shouldn't be changed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

And how/where should I stop it to generate new key?

Comment: I wish I knew. I've never heard of a server that generates a new key every day. After looking at the forums, it seems that perhaps that's how the mini server works. It might be worth posting a question there (http://www.coreftp.com/forums/viewforum.php?f=13)

Comment: :-(
I did post a question on it
http://coreftp.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=88666#88666
I am using mini server on another machine (the DR one) but it doesn't complain anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

You are losing any security by connecting to a SSH server that changes public key every day.

Anyway, if that's your only option, recent WinSCP allows accepting any host key automatically using the [`-hostkey=*` switch of the `open` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open#hostkey):

```
open -hostkey=*
```

You lose any security by doing that, but you are already, so it makes no difference.